# Can i update a part of a text-file? I have build a login-system and i want to count how many times a user has logged in

Tags: python, regex, file, expression

I want to ask to the community how i can update a part of a text-file without overwriting the text-file.

The project i am currently working on is called an login system.

The text-file contains the following values:
- username
- password
- date + time first time registered
- how many times the user has logged in.

But i want to know how i can update a part of a text file, every time a user had logged in i want to track it and write it to the earlier mentioned text-file.

- searched google
- stackoverflow

I don't know how to adjust the text-file without overwriting the values it contains.

Comment: You **should** overwrite the file in most cases - after reading it all and changing only the correct value (and writing everything back)

Comment: Rather than _just_ keeping all of this data in a text file, you might want to consider using a database. If this is a toy application (and you don't want to learn how to use a database), you might want to just keep the data you need in memory, in something like a list of `User` class objects. Then you can update the in-memory data, and periodically write it to a file in case of a crash (though this approach has other potential issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this is to actually overwrite the file if you're using text files.

Start by opening the file doing:

```
with open(file, "r") as read_file:
    string=read_file.read()
```

Then replace whatever it is you need to in the string, however way you wish to do that, as it is a string at that point.
Then just write it all again by doing:

```
with open(file, "w") as write_file:
    write_file.write(string)
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use `file` as both the _filename_ and _file object_.

Comment: @Tylerr thank you for your answer. Can you maybe advicehow i can adjust a part of a string (substring-method?) ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, if you're just isolating one part of the string and replacing it, simply do `stringhere.replace("oldSubString", "newSubString")` if this is everything, then mark the question as answered by clicking the tick next to my answer so people know to look here and I get the rep I need to help people in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot.  A text file is a sequence of bytes in fixed locations.

You *can* update only the one record, if you're very careful: make each user's entry a fixed length.  Find it and overwrite only that one short substring of the file.  If the new string is shorter, you will have to pad with blanks or other characters.  If it's longer, your original length estimate is invalid, and you have to omit something.

The application you describe is for some sort of data-base application, in which the file is a collection of records, indirectly addressed.  Also consider using a JSON structure.

---

For replacing a string of the same length, use the [tell](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_tell.htm) and [seek](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm) methods.

Use `tell` to recall the position of your string of interest.  Change the value, return to its position with `seek`, and then `write` the new string over the original.

I still recommend that you change to a data base representation; overwriting strings is a fragile way to maintain a data store.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I only need to increment one part of the string. Do you maybe know how to do that?